# Title Page Construction

Tags: titles

How would I render this title page in Latex?

[image]

So far, I have

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\author{A.\,N.~Other}
\title{Some things I did \\ Mathematics\\ Expiremental investigation}
\date{October, November 2016}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I need a way to make the "signature of sponsoring teachers and signature of student" lines and the Adress Line.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? Any limitations to what you can use in terms of (LaTeX) packages?

Comment: None whatsoever. I just want a title page that looks like the one posted, (with modifications, of course)

Comment: Please show us what you have. At least provide us with the dummy text in a compilable document e.g. `\title{}` etc. No fun starting from scratch with a do-it-all-for-me :(.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? I see the 'need' (so to speak) for the `center` environment, a `tabular` or `minipage`, some line drawing command like `\rule`, some command(s) related to vertical spacing, and commands related to font size and weight (e.g., bold). If you are unfamiliar with all of these, you should invest some time reading some basics like [*A Short In­tro­duc­tion to LaTeX2e*](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort).

Comment: I would do it from scratch, gives you the most freedom. Please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280

Comment: I am very new to LaTeX. Could you please show me how to do something? Any start would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

It is fairly easy to do this (not very pretty result) from scratch. It is explained in every LaTeX-introduction.

More information on creating a titlepage can be found in the [LaTeX-wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation) along with linked example title pages.

> [image: michaelTitlepage]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3em]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\sffamily\bfseries 
    {\centering
        \vspace*{14em}
        \Huge Effect of sunlight on plants
        \par\bigbreak
        Botany \par\bigbreak
        Experimental investigation\par
    }
    \vfill
    {\large
        Sponsoring teacher\par\vspace{3em}
School coordinator\par}
\vspace{5em}
\hfill\parbox{.25\linewidth}{%
    Alfred J. Kwak  \par
    Spetter Pieter Pater 12 \par
    2211 Zo vrolijk\par
}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```